# Automatic differentiation - Upper bound time

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Is there any proof or reference or intuition for the following theorem related to AAD:

Any function f of n variables f(x1,...,xn) can be differentiated with respect to every variable xi at a computational cost that does not exceed 4 times the complexity of one computation of f.

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

Comment: How is this link supposed to help ? Thank you

Comment: Backprop is a way to compute the gradient of a complex function -- it is an instance of automatic differentiation.  If you understand how/why backprop computes the gradient correctly, then I believe you will know all of the main ideas needed to prove the theorem yourself.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation, which also describes many of  the main ideas.

Comment: Do you mean "American Academy of Dermatology" ? Don't expect the acronyms to be obvious.

Comment: What is the connection between symbolic differentiation and function evaluation ???

Comment: I think I have found a proof on some book. @D.W: the proof is far from being obvious. Will post the ref later

Answer (score -1):

Proof can be found in section 4.4 and 4.5 of "evaluating derivatives and principles of algorithmic differentiation" from Griewank&Walther